# Git submodule untracked after merge of "previous" branch

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-merge

My git repos contains a master branch with the development version of our application and a branch for each released (or currently tested) version of the application.

Since the last branch we added a submodule to the master (=development) branch.

Today I had to make a few changes on the last branch which doesn't contain the submodule. When I check out this branch I always get a warning "warning: unable to rmdir Path/To/Submodule: Directory not empty" and the "Path/To/Submodule" will be listed as "untracked" when you do a "git status".
After making changes I always make certain that I selectively add the files before committing, so that I don't accidentally add the "Path/To/Submodule" to this branch.

When checking out the master branch again and simply merge using "git merge " the submodule is now listed as "untracked" in the master branch.

Looking at .gitmodules the submodule is still defined...

Any hints about how to recover this? Do I need to re-init the submodule?

Cheers,
Niels

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you would get those symptoms unless that directory was tracked at some point in your last branch's history then `git rm`ed for some reason.

That being said, if you re-init your submodule now, the next merge *shouldn't* remove it again, because the `rm` commit has already been merged.  That's certainly easier than trying to rewrite your last branch's history so the subdirectory was never present in the first place.